# Can we invite people to use our app or send friend request from the app via Facebook in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

Consider **X** and **Y** are friends in **Facebook** and they both have installed an app in their respective phones. But they are not friends with each other in that **app's friend list**. So now, can **X** ***send a friend request*** to **Y** from the app itself, so that they could be friends on the app's friends list?

Also in another case, **X** has installed this app in his phone, while **Y** has not. So again, can **X**  ***invite***  **Y** to use that app?

It tracks the people through the **email id** they have registered with in Facebook. So, **find friends** is for searching the "**already app users**", who are not in the app's friend list, but are friends in facebook and invite friends is for **inviting the non-users** of the app who are friends in Facebook.

My question is, is this possible in **iOS5** ie. without using the **Facebook sdk** which was introduced only in **iOS6**?

Comment: Why not you want to use Facebook-sdk 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Facebook-sdk 3.1](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/)

User-generated requests are initiated when the app enables the user to select one or more friends to send a request to.

We will walk you through the steps to send out an invite or a request:

- Triggering when the invitation or request is sent
- Sending the request
- Sending additional data with the request, such as a virtual gift

You can set up your app to prompt the user to send out an invite after the user has used the app a certain number of times. You should also give the user the ability to invite friends to use the app at any time through the use of a menu button they can always get to. In this step we will show you a simple way of triggering the invitation request.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/#protip2 for different types of coding logic.

See also:

1. [How to send add friend request (to facebook user) from iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521580/how-to-send-add-friend-request-to-facebook-user-from-ios-application)
2. [Can a facebook friend request be sent from my own app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360882/can-a-facebook-friend-request-be-sent-from-my-own-app)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook app id is same in both developer page and info in xcode next, enable sandbox mode,and must fill canvas url [under app on facebook category] in developer page.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"Your friend facebook id";
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

    NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
    NSString *title = @"TITLE";

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                  message:message
                title:title
                parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                        if (error)
                    {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                        NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                    {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                        NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Request Sent. %@", params);
                    }
        }}];
```