# Facebook SDK 3.2 for iOS 5 error with FBWebDialogs

Tags: objective-c, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.2 and I get the following error when calling FBWebDialog presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler when passing in the activeSession.

"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Here is my code:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
  message:msg title:nil parameters:nil
  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
    ...
  }];
```

It looks like NSDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript is only available in iOS6 or later, but I need to target iOS 5.0 for this project.

Is there anyway I can get FacebookSDK 3.2 to post requests to Facebook with iOS5?

Comment: What are the rest of the errors ? Have you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157784/can-we-invite-people-to-use-our-app-or-send-friend-request-from-the-app-via-face/16605625#16605625

Answer (score 1):

Try SDK 3.5. https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.5/
According to that page "The latest SDK supports iOS 5.0 and above."